# Angular reuse template and behavior

Tags: angularjs, templates, angularjs-directive

I'm using Angular JS and I would like to create a schedule control and use it in multiple pages. I would like to reuse HTML and JS code but in one page I will have on schedule and in another page I will have multiple schedules (one per person). I've been working on Angular for just a few weeks so be a little patience :)

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to organize your angular directory, if each schedule can be handled by logic that can be contained in a single `service` or the `service` can be instantiated by a factory (I'm not sure how you're currently handling the logic of the scheduler), then you can simply create a service for the schedule and inject your views based on the needs of how many schedule there is per page (such that either each schedule has its own "service" or methods that are unique to it, or that a singleton service can take parameters of many schedules and use the logic as required)

https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide